# How to save multiple numbers in one cell in a matrix/dataframe?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

This is R language.

From a matrix called temp_warnings that looks like

```
    row.names  row  day   Tx     Hx      Tn
1   61         61   30   31.9   36.85   19.1
2   84         84   23   33.5   43.07   20.3
3   85         85   24   31.5   39.82   19.2
4   94         94   2    30.9   41.36   20.0
5   99         99   7    34.0   43.17   21.6
6   101       101   9    34.4   42.45   21.0
7   131       131   8    30.1   38.52   19.6
8   132       132   9    30.7   38.35   21.0
```

I want to have this informations saved using the row and day columns into a new matrix called stn.

```
                             2001
Tmax >= 30 & Tmin >= 19     61, 84, 85, 94, 99, 101, 131, 132
May 
June                          30
July                        23, 24
August                      2, 7, 9
September                   8, 9
```

So I would like the contents of the column row to be saved in the first cell. There are 153 days being tested for Tx, Hx and Tn, May 1st - Sept 30th so the day column corresponds to the day of the month. So for column row numbers 1-31 are May, 32-61 are June and so on. I would like the day column numbers to be saved in the correct cells for their month as well.

If you need any other information let me know,
Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing

```
stn[1,1] <- toString(temp_warnings$row)
stn[2,1] <- toString((subset(temp_warnings, row <= 31))$day)
stn[3,1] <- toString((subset(temp_warnings, 31 < row & row <= 61))$day)
stn[4,1] <- toString((subset(temp_warnings, 61 < row & row <= 92))$day)
stn[5,1] <- toString((subset(temp_warnings, 92 < row & row <= 123))$day)
stn[6,1] <- toString((subset(temp_warnings, 123 < row))$day)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very unusual format so things can get messy:

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="row.names  row  day   Tx     Hx      Tn
1   61         61   30   31.9   36.85   19.1
2   84         84   23   33.5   43.07   20.3
3   85         85   24   31.5   39.82   19.2
4   94         94   2    30.9   41.36   20.0
5   99         99   7    34.0   43.17   21.6
6   101       101   9    34.4   42.45   21.0
7   131       131   8    30.1   38.52   19.6
8   132       132   9    30.7   38.35   21.0")


## creating a column for the months and pasting the days by month
dat <- within(dat, {
  m <- cut(row, breaks = c(0, 31, 61, 91, 121, Inf), labels = month.abb[5:9])
  ms <- ave(dat$day, m, FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse = ', '))
#   'Tmax >= 30 & Tmin >= 19' <- paste(row, collapse = ', ')
})

## creating the final data frame to merge into
dat1 <- data.frame(' ' = c('Tmax >= 30 & Tmin >= 19', month.abb[5:9]),
                   '2001' = c(paste(dat$row, collapse = ', '), rep(NA, 5)),
                   check.names = FALSE)

dat1 <- merge(dat1, dat[!duplicated(dat[c('m','ms')]), c('m','ms')],
              by.x = ' ', by.y = 'm', all = TRUE)

## combining the two columns and some clean-up
dat1 <- within(dat1, {
  '2001' <- gsub('NA', '', paste(`2001`, ms))
  ms <- NULL
  ' ' <- factor(` `, levels = c('Tmax >= 30 & Tmin >= 19', month.abb[5:9]))
})

## and ordering the rows as desired
dat1[with(dat1, order(` `)), ]

#                                                         2001
# 6 Tmax >= 30 & Tmin >= 19 61, 84, 85, 94, 99, 101, 131, 132 
# 4                     May                                   
# 3                     Jun                                 30
# 2                     Jul                             23, 24
# 1                     Aug                            2, 7, 9
# 5                     Sep                               8, 9
```